# Editing Sidebar in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

I am going to add a footer in the sidebar that generated using dynamic_sidebar function in Wordpress. As you know, dynamic_sidebar generate a sidebar with following structure:

```
<li class="sidebox">
    <h3>The Header</h3>

    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="sidebox">
    <h3>The Header</h3>

    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

But I want to convert it to:

```
<li class="sidebox">
    <h3>The Header</h3>

    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</li>
<li class="sidebox">
    <h3>The Header</h3>

    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</li>
```

How I can implement it?

Answer (score 0):

not sure how you would go about this in PHP, but if your JavaScript is fine, then you can do append child to the sidebox li, assuming that 1- footer contains the same content, OR 2- you have a differentiator (typically an id with incrementing number) to identify each individual block.